Setting Up RealSense Camera for 3D Mapping with RTAB-Map in ROS2 Humble
I'm trying to set up a RealSense D435i for 3D mapping using RTAB-Map in ROS2 Humble. I'm having trouble getting the launch files to work correctly and ensuring the proper communication between the realsense-ros and rtabmap_ros nodes.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.8.0-49-generic and ROS2 Humble. I've attempted to install librealsense and realsense-ros from source in my ROS2 workspace, and rtabmap_ros via binaries. However, I'm unsure of the correct versions and whether to download them through binary or from source. I am quite new to ROS so please guide me through each step.
Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on:
The recommended versions of librealsense, realsense-ros, and rtabmap_ros for ROS2 Humble.

Example launch files that correctly connect the RealSense camera to RTAB-Map for 3D mapping.

Any common ROS parameters that need to be set for proper operation.

